# Django Localization: How To Make 'po' file without HTML?

Tags: python, django

I would like my **po** translation file without any HTML.

So, in .po file we have:

```
msgid "PRODUCTS_WERE_ORDERED(%(b_sum)s)"
msgstr "Products were ordered for %(b_sum)s"
```

I wouldn't like the next (this is a solution but it's bad):

```
msgstr "Products were ordered for <b>%(b_sum)s</b>"
```

Finally I would like to make **b_sum** bold. The next code (in template) does not work:

```
{% with b_beg="<b>" b_end="</b>" %}
  <p>
    {% blocktrans with b_sum=sum %}PRODUCTS_WERE_ORDERED({{b_beg}}{{b_sum}}{{b_end}}){% endblocktrans %}
  </p>
{% endwith %}
```

After translation we have: PRODUCTS_WERE_ORDERED(**350**)

If we use

```
PRODUCTS_WERE_ORDERED({{b_sum}})
```

then we have: Products were ordered for 350 (without boldness).

Does anybody know how to make the sum bold not using HTML in **po** translation file?

Comment: By using another markup language?  Markdown, Textile, etc.

Comment: By using default Django tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by writing a custom template filter that formats a string with **sum** as parameter:

```
@register.filter( name='safewrap' )
def safewrap( val, arg ):
    return val.format( arg )
safewrap.is_safe = True
```

In this case we have in our template file:

```
{% blocktrans with sum2="<b>{0}</b>"|safewrap:sum %}PRODUCTS_WERE_ORDERED({{sum2}}){% endblocktrans %}
```

So our 'po' file is without HTML:

```
msgid "PRODUCTS_WERE_ORDERED(%(sum2)s)"
msgstr "This costs %(sum2)s"
```

Comment: Of course it's a still problem if we want to pass a string (which requires translation) instead of number.